# I am on the search for a X2Go solution for RASPI

Tags: python, arm

I am on the search for a *X2Go* solution for RASPI

I have had a quick lookup here at:

http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:repositories:debian

and

https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:development:build-server

Well I am not very sure if I can run the *x2GoServer Packages* on ARM - Well I guess that they are only available for intel platforms. No ARM packages.
I don't know if it's possible to build your own.

- Does anybody know any more information ?
- Can I compile this package for ARM architecture?

  -If so, does the *X2Go* run very slow on arm?

cf: https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:development:build-server

Comment: You may be able to build from source. There's source tarballs and a git at: https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/sources:start

Comment: You asked the same question here (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=228787#p1403200), and there was an answer last night

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see there is no need to build **X2go** from source for Raspbian. You can find a repository [X2Go Packages for Raspbian GNU/Linux](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:repositories:raspbian) with detailed instructions how to setup your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to get the prebuild packages for Raspbian Jessie and Stretch systems.